# Error on registering a cluster in GKE console

Tags: kubernetes, google-anthos

I have created a cluster on GCE and I am trying to register that in GKE console.

I have created a service account with the roles:

**roles/owner, 
roles/editor, 
roles/gkehub.connect**

But, when I try to register my remote-cluster on GKE console, I am getting below error. Cloud someone help me to get out of this?

*gcloud container hub memberships register remote-cluster --context=remote-cluster --service-account-key-file=./workdir/gkehub-7c3ea7087141.json*

**ERROR: (gcloud.container.hub.memberships.register) Failed to check if the user is a cluster-admin: Unable to connect to the server: context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anthos itself is not open source, so few people outside Google are familiar with how it works. You should contact Google support instead.

Comment: [The docs here](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/multicluster-management/connect/prerequisites#grant_iam_roles) say you need a few more roles (one of them gkehub.admin), try it with those.

Answer (score 1):

Install this sdk plugin solved my problem.

```
sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-gke-gcloud-auth-plugin
```